# How do I get Square's code gen utils working?

Tags: xcode5, code-generation

Square's [code generator utilities](http://corner.squareup.com/2014/02/objc-codegenutils.html) (objc-assetgen, objc-colordump, objc-identifierconstants) look great.

However, its documentation doesn't mention how to incorporate it into a project.

What's the best way to include these utilities in my project?

Answer (score 1):

Following the sample project's lead seems to be a good idea.

1. In finder, create a new folder called objc-codegenutils somewhere within your project directory structure.
2. Copy the following files/directories from the [official project](https://github.com/square/objc-codegenutils) into that folder:

   - assetgen
   - codegenutils.xcodeproj
   - colordump
   - identifierconstants
   - Shared
3. Drag codegenutils.xcodeproj from its new location in finder into the Xcode project navigator.
4. Add a new **Run Script** build phase for your target with the code located at the bottom of this post.
5. Drag the Run Script above the Compile Sources step.
6. Optionally, rename this step from Run Script to objc-codegentools.
7. In the Target Dependencies build phase, tap the plus button and choose the three codegenutils).
8. Create the Derived Sources folder in your project's root folder (i.e. the one referenced below). If this folder does not exist when you build your project, it will create all the files at the root folder.
9. Build the project so that your source code files are auto-generated.
10. Drag the Derived Sources folder from finder to the project navigator.
11. You can now #import any of the generated files and begin using them (e.g. `#import "MYMediaCatalog.h"` and `UIImage *image = [MYMediaCatalog myTestImage];`)
12. Optionally, #import the generated files in your `.pch` file so that you don't need to manually #import each one.

The advantages of setting up this way is that when the project is updated, you can simply replace everything in the objc-codegenutils with the updated code and it should work.

Run Script code:

```
DERIVED_SOURCES="$SRCROOT/Derived Sources"
TOOL_PATH=$BUILD_ROOT/$CONFIGURATION
$TOOL_PATH/objc-assetgen -f "$SRCROOT" -o "$DERIVED_SOURCES" -p MYP
$TOOL_PATH/objc-colordump -f "$SRCROOT" -o "$DERIVED_SOURCES" -p MYP
$TOOL_PATH/objc-identifierconstants -f "$SRCROOT" -o "$DERIVED_SOURCES" -p MYP
```

Note: replace MYP with your own [3 letter identifier](http://nshipster.com/namespacing/).

If you make any changes to how files are generated (e.g. if you create a new storyboard), you can recreate the Derived Sources using the following steps:

1. In Xcode, delete the Derived Sources group, choosing to send the files to the trash. (Warning: if you have any other files in this folder besides those that are auto generated, take care to only choose the correct files.)
2. Recreate the Derived Sources in finder.
3. Build the project.
4. Drag the Derived Sources folder in finder back into the project navigator in Xcode.

Note: If you have problems building, ensure that the codegenutils.xcodeproj is not open (sometimes you will have to restart Xcode in order for it to realize that it is closed), and that your target is set to iOS and not your mac.